# How do you write a unit test for a function that is not exported?

Tags: unit-testing, module, julia

I have a module that I'm writing unit tests for to run with travis.ci.

In my module I perform HTTP POST operations to a web service.

One of my internal only functions `validate_http_response()` is integral to the functions I'm creating to wrap around web service calls, so I'd like to test it. However, because there is no such `export validate_http_response` the function can't be "seen" by my test script and I get the error:

```
validate_http_response not defined
```

How should I structure my test so that I don't have to copy and paste the internal functions into the test itself (there are a few of them)? I'd like to prevent having to maintain a `src` and `test` script simultaneously.

**EDIT** Along with the accepted answer I also found I could do the following at the beginning of the test script: `include("../src/myfunctions.jl")`, as I have a separate test script for each file in the `src`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/modules/) on modules to better understand how namespacing works. There is no forced visibility in Julia, so you can always access functions, exported or non-exported, in any module by fully qualifying the reference.

So in your case, if your module is named `HTTP`, you could say `HTTP.validate_http_response` to access your unexported function to test.

Comment: Fully qualifying the reference is definitely the Julian way to handle this.

Comment: Works. I found it easier in the end to just do: `include("../src/myfunctions.jl")` so I don't have to reference it all the time.. lazy typing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two soltutions:

1. Export the function.
2. Create a new module which contains validation code for HTTP requests. Move the function there. Now it's part of an official/public API and can be tested independently.

The first solution is simple but soils your API. The second one is clean but probably a lot of work.